# How can I make a filters in "DataBound Application" template

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, filter

I try to make a small application like DVD library (without pretension I do not know programming). For this I use the predefined template "Windows Phone DataBound Application" but I wish I could filter data of type string in MainListBox (eg LineTwo contain different media types "dvd", "bluray "...). 
I guess I have to put in the file MainPage.xaml.cs something like:

`MainListBox.ItemsSelected = from c in ????? where ????? == "dvd"`

I just tried everything, but I failed, so if someone wanted to give me the exact code, it would be really nice. Please do not give me a link, normally I have read and tried to adapt (probably wrong) but without success.

Thank you in advance. 
Ghisura.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the filter at any time, then you should probably consider using a [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). You might find Geoff Hudik's [WP7 In-App Searching, Filtering](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html) blog post useful if you decide to take this route.

If you simply want to filter a source data set once, then LINQ is certainly a good solution for doing that, though you'll want to assign the result to the `ItemsSource` property. The details of the LINQ query will depend on your data set, but something like the following:

```
_listBox.ItemsSource = from c in mediaCollection
                       where c.MediaType == "dvd"
                       select c;
```

I know you've asked for the solution to be handed to you on a plater but a) it's not feasible given the limited information you've given, and b) it's not going to help you understand the problem and how to adapt a solution if your requirements change or you need to apply it to a similar situation. *Give* a man a fish and he eats for day; *teach* him how fish and he eats for life. :)

Comment: hello,

First of all thank you for taking the time to answer me.

during my research on google Linq (as you've told me) seems to be
The simplest approach to my problem. (1 single filter without changing it).

but I can not implement it. my problem is that I can
not determine my "mediaCollection". The template Windows Phone DataBound Application VB Studio 2010 may not be as simple as I thought.
I'll try to learn to fish :-) . 
Thank you

Comment: Where is the data you are using for your media collection? What is it that you actually need to bind to and where does it come from?

Comment: I solved  my  problem whith another source that I was also a problem,  but  this one I managed to fix it, so I can continue  my  little  project.
Thank you.